# Displaying decimal after number

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to display the following number, 40.0 by using this code:

```
Text{
 id: txt
 property int number: 40.0
 text: number
 x:94
 y:213
 font.family: "Helvetica"
 font.bold:true
 font.pointSize: 60
 color:"#fff"
        }
```

For some reason, only 40 is displaying, and no decimal. These are the other things I've tried so far:

  1.

```
str = QString::number(flat, 'f', 40.0);
```

  2.

```
var german = Qt.locale("de_DE");
var d;
d = Number.fromLocaleString(german, "40.0")   // d == 40.0
```

  3.

```
Text {
 Number(40.0).toLocaleString(Qt.locale("de_DE"))
}
```

Comment: change `property int number: 40.0` to `property real number: 40.0`

Comment: I did that and my number disappeared completely.

Comment: Use `property real number: 40.0` `text: Number(number).toLocaleString(Qt.locale("de_DE"))`

Comment: That gave me a Invalid attached object assignment

Answer (score 1):

- Since you are working with real numbers, type should be `real`.
- In QML you can use [JS's toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to format a number using fixed-point notation.
- To bind property value to a function you should do as follows:

```
Text {
    id: txt
    property real number: 40.1
    text: {
        return txt.number.toFixed(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: I confirmed it works. The interesting situation is when you do some mathematic calculations like: (txt.number / 10) * 10 in such case required is to use js function Number() to convert the value to float.